# socket.io web connection failed

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, sockets, socket.io

I'm building a chat Application using node js and react js . I got some error in cross-origin , that i tries to solve using `npm core` , after solving the cors error i got this error

```
websocket.js:50 WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:5000/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket' failed:
```

i have tried couple of different method like adding `transports : ['websocket']`
but it doesn't seems to work for me

I'm dealing with socket for the first time , maybe making a silly mistake  , let me know if any expert can help me solve the probem i'm just stuck in this error watches different videos and applied couple of different code from stackOverflow but doesn't work for me

**here is my server code**

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express();
const socket =  require('socket.io')
const http = require('http')
const Port = 5000 || process.env.Port;
const cors = require('cors')
const myRouter  = require('./router/router');
const server = http.createServer(app)
const io = socket(server)


 app.use(cors({
     origin : "*"
 }))

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    console.log('A user has connected');
 
    //Whenever someone disconnects this piece of code executed
    socket.on('disconnect', function () {
       console.log('A user has disconnected');
    });
 });

app.use('/',myRouter)


app.listen(Port,()=>{
    console.log(`App is running at http://localhost:${Port}`)
})
```

**here is my client side code after user redirected to chat components**

```
import React from 'react'
import querystring from 'query-string';
import io from 'socket.io-client';
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useState } from 'react';


let Socket;

export default function Chat() {
  const [name, setName] = useState('')
  const [room, setRoom] = useState('')

  const Endpoint = 'localhost:5000'

  // ^ to get location of current window 
  const location = window.location;

  useEffect(() => {
    const { name, room } = querystring.parse(location.search);
    Socket = io(Endpoint , {transports: ["websocket"]})
    setName(name)
    setRoom(room)
    console.log(Socket)
  }, [location.search, Endpoint])

  return (
    <div>
      <h1> lets chat</h1>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: replace your socket import and initialization as const { Server } = require("socket.io");
const io = new Server(server);

Comment: tried , doesn't work

Comment: ok..after that change  const Endpoint = 'localhost:5000' to  const Endpoint = http://'localhost:5000' and Socket = io(Endpoint , {transports: ["websocket"]}) to Socket = io(Endpoint , {transports: ["websocket", "polling"]}).  Try this if still not workin gthat must be issue with your local firewall or network

Comment: I tried turning off firewall still nothings works